# 2 ids in one row, firstname and lastname in other. How to receive firstname from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm struggling with 1 excercise since month I guess and hope you can help me. I've tried subquery in from, with or join tables in many ways and didn't received proper result.

OK. One row in Table1 stores information like:

- Client's ID
- firsname
- lastame
- Waiter id

One row in Table2 stores information like:

- userID (client and waiter are the user)
- firstname
- lastname

[image: I've attaced picture how those tables look]

I'm new to SQL but how I see this is:

```
WITH waiter AS(
  SELECT
   waiter_id,
   firstname,
   lastname
 FROM Table1
 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.waiter_id = Table2.user_id
 )
 SELECT
  client_id,
  firstname as Firstname_client,
  lastname as Lastname_client,
  waiter_id,
  waiter.firstname as Firstname_waiter,
  waiter.lastname as Lastname_waiter
 FROM Table1
 JOIN waiter ON Table1.waiter_id = waiter.waiter.id
```

I would be very grateful for any clues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query. just use an alias name and `JOIN`

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    client_id int,
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname  varchar(50),
    waiter_id int
);
INSERT INTO Table1 values (1,'Andrew','x',5);
INSERT INTO Table1 values (2,'Chris','xx',6);
INSERT INTO Table1 values (3,'Anna','xxx',7);
INSERT INTO Table1 values (4,'Julia','xxxx',8);

CREATE TABLE Table2(
    user_id int,
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname  varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Table2 values (1,'Andrew','x');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (2,'Chris','xx');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (3,'Anna','xxx');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (4,'Julia','xxxx');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (5,'Mat','xxxxx');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (6,'Kathy','xxxxxx');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (7,'Pual','xxxxxxx');
INSERT INTO Table2 values (8,'John','xxxxxxxx');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.client_id ,
        t1.firstname AS Firstance_client,
        t1.lastname as Lastname_Client,
        t1.waiter_id,
        t2.firstname as  Firstname_waiter ,
        t2.lastname as Lastname_Waiter
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.waiter_id = t2.user_id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58cc84/1)

**[Results]**:

```
| client_id | Firstance_client | Lastname_Client | waiter_id | Firstname_waiter | Lastname_Waiter |
|-----------|------------------|-----------------|-----------|------------------|-----------------|
|         1 |           Andrew |               x |         5 |              Mat |           xxxxx |
|         2 |            Chris |              xx |         6 |            Kathy |          xxxxxx |
|         3 |             Anna |             xxx |         7 |             Pual |         xxxxxxx |
|         4 |            Julia |            xxxx |         8 |             John |        xxxxxxxx |
```

Comment: What's your dbms? mysql or mssql or another?

Comment: It's mysql and receiving no data when trying query those

Comment: it looks like something is wrong with database. Thank you all once again for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get third table

```
    Select ClientId, 
    c.FirstName as Client_FirstName, 
    c.LastName Client_LastName,
    w.FirstName as Waiter_FirstName, 
    w.LastName as Waiter_LastName, 
    w.UserId as WaiterId
    FROm dbo.Table1 as c
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Waiter as[enter image description here][1] w on c.WaiterId = w.UserId
```

[Sql Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTpAu.png)